# Why can't I dispose my source FileSystemWatcher object?

Tags: powershell

I have a `FileSystemWatcher` Script which does create a `FileSystemWatcher` for each Subfolder that matches a regex. This works like a charm.
Here's my script

```
$Folders = gci $Dir -Dir | ? Name -match '^\d{5}$' | % {

    $source = $_.FullName
    $watcher = [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher]::new()
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    $watcher.Path = $source
    $watcher.Filter = "*.csv"
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $watcher

}

$action = { stuff }

Get-Variable | ? Name -match '^\d{5}$' | % {

    Register-ObjectEvent $_.Value Created -Action $action -SourceIdentifier $_.Name > $null

}
```

This leaves me with some FileSystemWatchers in different Variables like `$70447`, `$78900`, `$13450` etc.

but I also have one watcher in `$watcher`, but this variable is only used to pass my `FileSystemWatcher Object` to the "productive" 5-digit variables

I wanted to get rid of `$watcher` by doing a `$watcher.dispose()` after the `New-Variable` Command. But when I do this, all of my watchers throw an error.

Why does this happen? `$watcher` is not in use anymore since the object is already passed on to a new variable. Can someone explain this?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot access thrown Object.
Objektname: "FileSystemWatcher".
In Z:\Powershell-Scripts\FSW.ps1:43 Zeichen:5
+     Register-ObjectEvent $_.Value Created -Action $action -SourceIden ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.IO.FileSystemWatcher:FileSystemWatcher) [Register-ObjectEvent], ObjectDisposedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : INVALID_REGISTRATION,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RegisterObjectEventCommand
```

Comment: Multiple variables can reference the same object. If you dispose object thru one variable, then it will be disposed regardless which variable you use to reference it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, the references are getting tied to the variables somehow and disposing is causing some kind of scope issue.  I'm unable to replicate your problem, but consider not having in-between variable assignments and see if it resolves your issue:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Directory | ? Name -match '^\d{5}$' | % {
    New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value (New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{
        IncludeSubdirectories = $false
        Path                  = $_.FullName
        Filter                = '*.csv'
        EnableRaisingEvents   = $true
    })
}

$action = { stuff }

Get-Variable | ? Name -match '^\d{5}$' | % {
    $null = $_.Value | Register-ObjectEvent -EventName Created -Action $action -SourceIdentifier $_.Name
}
```